# Bluemix buildpack for liferay/tomcat : failed to accept connections within health check timeout

Tags: tomcat, liferay, ibm-cloud, devops, buildpack

I am trying to deploy liferay-buildpack to Bluemix by:

```
git clone https://github.com/shinji62/liferay-buildpack <br/>
cd liferay-buildpack <br/>
cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net <br/>
cf login <br/>
    Email> xxxxxxx <br/>
    Password> xxxxxx <br/>
cf push liferaytest201602 -c 'bin/startup.sh' -p . <br/>
```

But the deployment failed and I couldn't start liferay with these errors:

```
...
"exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1454828817}
...
```

It seems like there is something wrong with the port listening setting.

Could someone please help and let me know how to solve this problem?

Thanks and best regards,

Akira Fujiwara

-----adding information -----

Thank you very much for your comment.
I re-tried as below:

1. download liferay bundled with tomcat zip file from https://www.liferay.com/en/downloads/liferay-portal/available-releases
2. command:

> ```
> tar xvf liferay-portal-tomcat-6.2-ce-ga6-20160112152609836.zip
> cd liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga6     
> cf api http://api.ng.bluemix.net
> cf login    
>     Email> xxxxxxx
>     Password> xxxxxxx
>
> cf push akiraliferay -b https://github.com/shinji62/liferay-buildpack -c 'tomcat-7.0.62/bin/startup.sh’ .
> ```

But the error occurs like:

```
[Buildpack]                      ERROR Compile failed with exception
 #<RuntimeError: No container can run this application. Please ensure 
that you’ve pushed a valid JVM artifact or artifacts using the -p 
command line argument or path manifest entry. Information about valid 
JVM artifacts can be found at 
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack#additional-documentation. >
```

I also tried :

```
cf push akiraliferay -b https://github.com/shinji62/liferay-buildpack -c 'tomcat-7.0.62/bin/startup.sh’
```

But the result was the same.

Could you please help me how to solve it?
I appreciate much if you help me to solve this issue.

regards,

Akira Fujiwara

Comment: thank you for your answer, I edited it for additional question.

Answer (score 0):

You can not push a buildpack to Bluemix. A buildpack provides the framework for your application. You can push an application and specify the buildpack you want Bluemix/CloudFoundry to use to run that application.

`cf push <appName> -b <buildpack> -p <path of your app>`

For example:

`cf push myliferayapp -b https://github.com/shinji62/liferay-buildpack -p target/myliferayapp.war`